# Samba mounted as owner, but still can't change permissions

Tags: samba, freebsd, file-permissions, samba4

I've set up a Samba server on my FreeBSD, and it is basically all working exactly as expected. Except for one thing: I can't change file permissions, even when I mount the share as the owning uid. Neither on Windows nor Linux clients. Here's my config:

```
 [global]
    netbios name = SERVER
    realm = SERVER.CH
    workgroup = SERVER
    unix extensions = yes
    ea support = yes
    dns forwarder = 192.168.0.2
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
[share]
    path = /path/to/share
    guest ok = no
    writeable = yes
```

I guess there's something I have to add to the config for it to work?

Comment: Can you give more details on what exactly happens, what are you executing, perhaps an example or two?

Comment: I'm mounting the share with the login credentials of the directory owner and try to change file permissions. This works neither in a file manager nor on command line. I tried mounting on Windows, and on Linux using both CIFS and the kio SMB mount. No fancy special arguments, just a plain old mount.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- Check that **/path/to/share** is owned by the user you are using and she has full permissions on it
  `ls -lad /path/to/share`
- Check the **create mask**, **directory mask** parameters
- Check map * parameters
- Check force * parameters
- More details on how permissions work in samba https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html#INDEX-30 https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html

Comment: Yes, the path is owned by the correct user. Reading/writing otherwise works fine, and the correct server owner uid is displayed. The above is my whole samba config, so there aren't any more parameters and masks I could check :)

Comment: Well creation mask and directly mask have defaults, 744 i think.